# Find the maximum value on the selected cells

Tags: excel, vba

right now i am starting programming with vba and i am finding difficulties on understanding the variable logic on it.

- What i would like to do with it, is to find the maximum value on a specific row at the users choosing.
- From what i know of programming and also from an internet research i have reached this code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub LimiteSuperioremK4()
'
' LimiteSuperioremMaq5 Macro
'
    Dim teste As Double
    Dim teste1 As String
    Dim teste2 As String
    Dim nTamanhoCell As Integer
    Dim xTitleid As String
    Dim rcell As Double
    Dim Max As Double
    Dim x As Integer
    xTitleid = "Retirar Números de Texto"
    teste1 = Application.InputBox("Porfavor selecione a lista de argumentos que quer retirar:", xTitleid, "", Type:=10)
    ' If TypeName(teste1) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
    teste2 = Application.InputBox("Por favor selecione onde quer colocar, a lista de elementos retirada:", xTitleid, "", Type:=10)
    ' If TypeName(teste2) = "Nothing" Then Exit Sub
        Max = 0 'set "inital" max
            nTamanhoCell = Len(teste1)
            rcell = nTamanhoCell
        For rcell = 1 To nTamanhoCell
            If rcell > Max Then
            Max = rcell
            End If
            Next rcell
    End Sub
```

Data worked:
" KG - 0.785; 0.857; 0.652 and so on and so on... " values between 0 and 1.

So the question i would like to ask is, why does it keep telling that i don´t give the object on "teste1" when i choose the values of it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because you have declared `teste` to be of type `Range`, which is an object

Comment: Yeah i need it to go though the row of values to find the highest one don´t i?
I will try and set it to a  value or delete it

Comment: Also, check what happens with your code if the inputbox for teste1 or teste2 is a string instead of a range.

Comment: Nice suggestion, didn´t think of using a string as the array of numbers!
Thanks Ron!
Will edit or comment if i have some results!!

Much appreciated the help, in the company nobody even looks at my code, tfelling gratefull bro!

Comment: I see you have edited your question since my response and are now inquiring about `teste1` and not `test`.  The reason `teste1` requires an object is because you are using the `Set` word and are probably feeding it a string.

Comment: Yes i edited because i made a mistake on the first post about it... i think teste will also break my code when i reach the "for each" but i will check that later, right now i just want my code to read the values of a row of numbers...

Comment: Well if i put the teste1 as a string, it breaks on the "for each" command, will try to make only a for with it and see if it works.

Thanks again for the help! Really appreciate it!

Comment: Don't use `Set`.  Then `teste1` will become a 2D array of the values within the selected range, instead of the range object itself.  You can then examine the array elements to do your comparison.  Or you can just apply `Application.Worksheetfunction.Max` to the array.

Comment: Heya, so i have used the max funcion on it, and i find it hard to understand what it needs, because i feed him the array of values and it doesn´t even give me out anything, saying that it is not possible to get it.....

Comment: Will edit the code.. but now it doesn´t give an error, it just doesn´t give me anything on the selected cell...

Comment: Without knowing your data input or how you have modified your code, it is not possible for me to comment further. You could edit your question to add the relevant information and I'd be happy to take a look at it.

Comment: Okay i will try to explain, i can also post some of the data, because it is almost all the same.
It is a rows of weights, taken second after second so imagine a row of 0.xxx and 0.yyy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a logic that's serving another purpose.

This is just for learning purposes as mentioned in the comments, you'd solve this with a function or another method.

Also some suggestions:

- Name your procedure and variables to something meaningful
- Indent your code (you may use Rubberduckvba.com)
- Split the logic in steps

Read the code's comments and step into it using `F8` key

---

**Code:**

```
Public Sub WriteMaxFromRange()
    
    ' Get the range of values from user
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim messageTitle As String
    messageTitle = "Retirar Números de Texto"
    Set sourceRange = Application.InputBox("Por favor selecione a lista de argumentos que quer retirar:", messageTitle, "", Type:=8)
    
    ' Validate if user selected something and is more than one cell
    If sourceRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If sourceRange.Cells.CountLarge = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Get the destination cell
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = Application.InputBox("Por favor selecione onde quer colocar, a lista de elementos retirada:", messageTitle, "", Type:=8)
    
    ' Validate if user selected something and is just one cell
    If targetRange Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If targetRange.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Iterate through cells and find max
    Dim maxValue As Double
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    For Each sourceCell In sourceRange.Cells
        ' Skip text
        If Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(sourceCell.Value) Then
            ' Compare with and update max
            If sourceCell.Value > maxValue Then
                maxValue = sourceCell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next sourceCell
    
    ' Write max value in target cell
    targetRange.Value = maxValue
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for those tips... yeah i know i make a bit of a mess, i will try and do it like you, naming after the things i want...
Seems really the best way to read and write your code is splitting it to logic steps.
I appreciate your time, also it helped me a lot understanding your code to write mine better. i will make it from scratch guiding myself with your answer!!

Again thanks for your time and dedication!!

Comment: Sure, let me just write mine and check it, i will gladly upvote and put a checkmark on it!
For what i have read i think it will get the maximum value out of a string so yeah that´s what i wanted.
Thanks a lot for your time!! Again i appreciate it!!